# Custom CSS Disables Button Functionality

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm currently working with the WordPress theme evont and trying to do some custom css on the homepage. There is a button on the home page that is too low on the page so I tried doing some custom css to raise it.

Whenever I change the margin-top value, the button no longer clicks or animates. Can not seem to figure out what is causing this.

First picture is of the animation that happens when hovering, before touching any css.

Second picture is what happens when hovering, after touching the css.

[image]

[image]

Below is the code for the button that I could find:

```
.jx-month-small .event-ticket-btn {
     font-size: 50px;
     font-family: 'Oswald';
     font-weight: 500;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     background: #000;
     line-height: 1;
     padding: 15px 80px 15px 30px;
     margin-top:140px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 82%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -45px;
    transition: .3s all ease-out;
}

.jx-month-small .event-ticket-btn:hover {
    margin-left: -95px;
}

.jx-month-small .event-ticket-btn a {
    color:#fff
}

.jx-month-small .event-ticket-btn a:hover {
    color:#fff300
}
```

Comment: There is probably another element that by moving this one "up" you're actually moving it "up and under" the other. If you can provide all the  HTML and css to replicate we can probably help you. In the meantime, try adding a `z-index:2` to the button you're moving and see if that helps

Comment: Changing the z-index fixed the issue. I had tried changing it before, but whatever was on top must have been a higher value. Changed it to 100 and now it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what about trying to add

```
bottom: 200px;
```

or

```
top: 80%;
```

something like that since its absolutely positioned.

would help to see the html code associated with it.

Comment: Potentially worth leaving "suggestions" of solutions to comments, rather than submitting them as answers :)

Comment: Ahh kk will keep that in mind. Still learning the ropes of this great community. joined today :)